# Sturdy noise cancelling/isolating earbuds

Tags: audio, headphones, earphones

I am looking for some sturdy (they will be travelling quite a lot) noise cancelling or, at this price, more likely noise isolating in-ear earphones. I will mostly be listening to classical music and voices, so bass is not as important to me as it may be to others.

My research so far has brought me across the Sennheiser CX 175 however; I have read a somewhat worrying number of reviews that mention less than perfect build quality.

I am wanting to spend somewhere less than £50 ($75) and I would rather spend less for best quality per money than max out my budget.

Comment: Do you want a active noise cancelling earbud or a passive noise cancelling one?

Comment: @peterzhu2118 I not really bothered I just want the best external noise reduction at this price point. (I am guessing that at this price I am going to be better off with  passive/noise isolating)